# Aleatorios en bucle se generan iguales

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Estoy haciendo un trabajo y necesito crear varios objetos cliente con DNIs aleatorios, pero todos los datos generados en el bucle son iguales, `srand(time(NULL))` se genera al inicio del programa y fuera del bucle.

Código con bucle para generar los datos y añadirlos a una pila:

```
void Gestor::iniciar_pila(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        Cliente c1;
        reserva.ordenado(c1);
    }
}
```

Codigo donde se crea el objeto:

```
#include "Cliente.h"
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <random>
using namespace std;
Cliente::Cliente()
{
    registrado = rand() % 2;
    llegada = rand() % 60;
    genDNI();
    char letra= genLetraDNI(intDNI());
    DNI[8]=letra;

//ctor
}
Cliente::Cliente(bool regis)
{
    registrado = regis;
    llegada = rand() % 60;
    genDNI();
    char letra= genLetraDNI(intDNI());
    DNI[8]=letra;

//ctor
}

Cliente::Cliente(bool regis,char dni[10]){
    registrado = regis;
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
        DNI[i] = dni[i];}
    llegada = rand() % 60;}

Cliente::~Cliente(){
    //dtor
}

void Cliente::genDNI(){
        for (int i=0;i<8;i++){
            char num="0123456789"[rand()%10];
            DNI[i]=num;
    }
}
int Cliente::intDNI(){
    int intdni = 0;
    for (int i=7;i>=0;i--){
        float mult=pow(10,7-i);
        intdni = intdni + (DNI[i]-'0')*(int)mult;
    }
    return(intdni);
}
char Cliente::genLetraDNI(int valor){
    char letras[24]="TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE";
    return (letras[(valor%23)]);
}
void Cliente::verCliente(){

    if(registrado==1){
        cout<<"Usuario registrado\n";
    }else{cout<<"Usuario no registrado\n";}
    if(llegada<=10){
        cout<<"Hora de llegada: 10:0"<<llegada<<"\n";
    }else{
        cout<<"Hora de llegada: 10:"<<llegada<<"\n";
    }
    cout<<"DNI: "<<DNI<<"\n";

}
bool Cliente::esRegistrado(){
    return registrado;
}
```

Siempre da este tipo de resultados.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto un enlace con el código en rar por si alguien quiere probarlo

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nCed1YLkgVpaph_YfHJm_FFLM--4jTvq/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3):

El código que muestras es correcto. El problema está en el código *que no muestras* (menos mal que has proporcionado un enlace al código completo).

Ocurre que cada `Cliente` tiene un atributo de tipo `Concierto`, como se puede observar en el fichero de cabecera `Cliente.h`:

```cpp
class Cliente
{
    public:
        Cliente();
        Cliente(bool regis);
        Cliente(bool regis,char dni[10]);
        void genDNI();
        int intDNI();
        char genLetraDNI(int valor);
        void verCliente();
        bool esRegistrado();
        ~Cliente();

    protected:

    private:
        bool registrado;
        int llegada;
        char DNI[9];
        Concierto conc;   // <---- AQUI ESTA EL COMPLICE

};
```

Y ocurre que en el constructor del Concierto, reinicias la semilla aleatoria, como se ve en esta línea de `Concierto.cpp`:

```cpp
Concierto::Concierto()
{
    srand(time(NULL));   // <------ Y AQUI ESTA EL CULPABLE
    asiento = rand()% 1001;
    identificador = rand()% 4 + 1;
}
```

Y ahora la explicación de qué está sucediendo.

La generación de números aleatorios con `rand()` no es verdaderamente aleatoria. Es simplemente una secuencia de números *de aspecto aleatorio*, pero que es determinista. La secuencia concreta depende del valor de la *semilla*, que es lo que se inicializa con la llamada a `srand()`.

En tu caso a `srand()` le pasas como parámetro `time(NULL)`, lo que hace que capture la hora del sistema en ese momento (es en realidad un entero que es un contador de segundos) y se le pase ese valor como semilla. Así, al ejecutar esa instrucción en diferentes momentos, ya que la hora es diferente, la semilla aleatoria será también diferente, por lo que la secuencia de números *pseudoaleatorios* que `rand()` generará será también diferente.

**Ahora bien**, si llamas a `time(NULL)` en intervalos de tiempo muy cortos, es posible que no haya transcurrido un segundo entre llamada y llamada. En ese caso el valor retornado por `time()` será el mismo en todas esas llamadas (todas las que tengan lugar dentro del mismo segundo).

Eso es exactamente lo que está ocurriendo en tu caso. Intentas generar cinco clientes aleatorios con este bucle:

```
void Gestor::iniciar_pila(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        Cliente c1;
        reserva.ordenado(c1);
    }
}
```

para lo que inicias la semilla aleatoria. Pero ya que cada cliente internamente tiene un `Concierto` y éste vuelve a hacer `srand(time(NULL))` en un periodo muy corto de tiempo, **cada cliente vuelve a iniciar la semilla con el mismo valor**, por lo que cada cliente obtiene la misma secuencia de valores pseudoaleatorios en `rand()` y al final todos los clientes salen iguales.

Para colmo este problema es difícil de depurar, porque si haces la ejecución paso a paso dentro del depurador es bastante posible que cada nuevo cliente se genere en un segundo distinto, con lo que la semilla se inicializará a un valor diferente y en ese caso sí obtendrás clientes diferentes. Sólo si ejecutas fuera del depurador, los cinco clientes se crearán tan rápido que lo harán en el mismo segundo y por tanto saldrán iguales.

### Solución

Elimina las llamadas a `srand(time(NULL))` que tenías dentro de los constructores de la clase `Concierto()`.

### Moraleja

Mejor llamas a `srand(time())` *una sola vez* en todo el programa, cuando este arranque. No por llamarle más veces vas a tener números más aleatorios, sino que de hecho puede suceder lo contrario como acabas de comprobar.

Comment: Pensé que como no generaba en ningún momento un objeto concierto, su constructor no se ejecutaría nunca por lo que no se me paso por la cabeza revisar esa parte

Comment: Al crear un cliente, ya que este tiene un campo de tipo concierto, necesariamente se crea un objeto de tipo concierto, lo que llama a su constructor sin parámetros.